# Select only one row for a user when there are multiple rows for that user based on a condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a multi column table that I have derived by joining other tables

| UserId. | Attempts. | quizno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | assd. |
| First | 2 | ffjfjf. |
| Second | 1 | cbcbc. |
| Second | 2 | tititi. |
| Second | 3 | cncncn. |

I want a table that returns the row for each user with the highest attempt

| UserId. | Attempts. | quizno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2 | ffjfjf |
| Second | 3 | cncncn |

Comment: Would that get the entire row ? There are other columns too for that row .

Comment: That's a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

Answer (score 2):

That's a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). It selects the first/top per group: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-CF9bfQg)

```sql
select distinct on ("UserId.") *
from user_attempts
order by "UserId.", "Attempts." desc;
```

| UserId. | Attempts. | quizno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2 | ffjfjf. |
| Second | 3 | cncncn. |

You're telling it in the parentheses which fields decide what a group is, similar to a `group by`, then in the `order by` you need to repeat that list followed by the fields which together decide which rows ends up as the "top" one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I guess that your table has more than 2 columns rather than just two.
If you only have 2 columns, what @Abra put in the comment works.

One suggestion is:

```
SELECT UserId, quizno, Attempts 
FROM (
SELECT UserId, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Attempts DESC) RowNuber,
       quizno, Attempts 
FROM TABLE
) a
WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Updated the question, yes, there are other columns too in that row.

Answer (score -1):

My solution.

Creating the [database] table:

```sql
create table UAQ (USER_ID varchar(6), ATTEMPTS int, QUIZNO varchar(7))
```

I populate the table with sample data from your question.

My query:

```sql
select T1.USER_ID, T1.ATTEMPTS, T1.QUIZNO
  from UAQ T1
  join (select USER_ID, max(ATTEMPTS) as BIG from UAQ group by USER_ID) T2
    on (T1.USER_ID = T2.USER_ID and T1.ATTEMPTS = T2.BIG)
```

Note that table `T2` contains the maximum attempts per user.

My results:

| user_id | attempts | quizno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2 | ffjfjf. |
| Second | 3 | cncncn. |

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bJuj1UA5)